# How to call a non-angular callback within a directive

Tags: angularjs, callback, directive

Is there a correct way to pass a non-angular callback (preferably an anonymous function) name to a directive and then have it activated from the directive. My motivation is to interface from the directive to legacy non-angular code.

Here is what I want:

```
<my-Directive callback="function (param) {some-legacy-function(param)}">
```

and then have it activated:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($scope) {
   return {
      scope: {
        callback: '&'
      }
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.someMethod = function() {
           $scope.callback($scope.param);
      }
   }
});
```

Note that callback function is not defined on any scope and should preferably anonymous (but I can manage with a non-anonymous function as well).

I found one of doing this by simply passing a string and then doing an eval to call the method but after reading around I understand this approach is problematic (security wise).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: expressions are always evaluated on the scope. Why would you have this JS code in the HTML view rather than the controller code?

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your legacy code inside a injectable service, so you can inject it anywhere (and replace/mock it for tests)

```
// here set on global for example
var legacyFunction=function(){};

//angular code (has to be loaded after your "old" script
myApp.factory('legacyFunction',function(){
   return legacyFunction;
})

//now it is available anywhere in you application (directives, controllers, etc) as an injectable -here in a controller so you can bind it to a $scope for example

myApp.controller('myController',['$scope', 'legacyFunction', function($scope, func){
    $scope.myFunc = func 
}])
```

Comment: `factory` is a method of `angular.module`, not the `angular` object.